# how to get textBox in GridView when click on edit button using Hovermenu and Get RowIndex..?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, textbox, hover

Hi i m using GridView with hovermenu
and i want that when we click on edit button then we get TextBox to write in Gridview
and also i get error when click on edit for e.commandArgument is null
so please give me code for this both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your edit button command name like this,

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkEdit" runat="server" 
  CausesValidation="false"  CommandName="EditRow" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
```

and in `RowCommand` event of ur gridview

```
if (e.CommandName == "EditRow")
{
   TextBox tbx =  (TextBox)gridCategory.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].FindControl("UrTxtID");
}
```

Any how its really difficult to tell what you are doing wrong without seeing your code..

**EDIT:**

i think you need to set `CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'` in your edit button...

Comment: @Pandiya Chendur, Code is good but i get e.CommandArgument = ""
so  again it gives error of FormatException

Answer (score 0):

I ran across your post while searching for a way to get the current row in a gridview rowcommand event.
I also ran across this link and thought I'd share:
http://ranafaisal.wordpress.com/2008/03/31/how-to-get-the-current-row-in-gridview-row-command-event/

This solved my problem and seems very clean.