# How to get data from TextBox in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is the code where I have problem, I don't have any problems in the previous page but this is happening in this and following page.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv_employee" runat="server" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowEditing="Edit" OnRowCancelingEdit="CancelEdit" OnRowUpdating="Update" Width="1070px"
                            AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="WhiteSmoke" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#C5D9F1">
                            <Columns>

                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S.No" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="60px">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employee Code" ItemStyle-Width="160px">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_gv_empcode" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("employeecode")%>' />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employee Name">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_gv_empname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("employeename") %>' />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_gv_empname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("employeename") %>' />
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address1">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_gv_addr1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("address1") %>' />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_gv_addr1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("address1") %>' />
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>

<%--                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address2">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_gv_addr2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("address2") %>' />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_gv_addr2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("address2") %>' />
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address3">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_gv_addr3" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("address3") %>' />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_gv_addr3" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("address3") %>' />
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>


                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_gv_city" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("city")%>' />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_gv_city" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("city")%>' />
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>--%>


                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_gv_email" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("email") %>' />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_gv_email" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("email") %>' />
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>


                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Phone">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_gv_phone" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("phone") %>' />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_gv_phone" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("phone") %>' />
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" />
                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="btndel" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("employeecode") %>'
                                            OnClientClick="return confirm('Do you want to delete?')" OnClick="Delete" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                            </Columns>

                        </asp:GridView>
```

This is my asp code

```
public void BindData()
{
    string ls_sqlcmd = "select * from employeemst";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(ls_sqlcmd);
    gv_employee.DataSource = add.GetData(cmd);
    gv_employee.DataBind();
}


protected void Delete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lnk_deletestate = (LinkButton)sender;
    string str = "delete from employeemst where employeecode='" + lnk_deletestate.CommandArgument + "'";
    add.adddata(str);
    BindData();
}

protected void Update(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{

    String emplname = ((TextBox)gv_employee.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_gv_empname")).Text;  
    String Addr1= ((TextBox)gv_employee.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_gv_addr1")).Text;  
    String addr2 = ((TextBox)gv_employee.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_gv_addr2")).Text;  
    String addr3 = ((TextBox)gv_employee.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txt_gv_addr3")).Text;  

    gv_employee.EditIndex = -1;
    BindData();
}

protected void Edit(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    gv_employee.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    BindData();
}

protected void CancelEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    gv_employee.EditIndex = -1;
    BindData();
}
```

}

This is my aspx.cs code.

My problem is that I am unable to get data from textbox which is in gridview `<EditItemTemplate></EditItemTemplate>`

I don't get updated value in string `emplname`, `addr1`, `addr2`,`addr3`.

Comment: please be specific, add relevant code only

Comment: Expanding on what@un-lucky said. Make you example smaller and format your code better. The easier you make our lives, the easier it is for us to help you.

Comment: Try going over [this](https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/master-pages/control-id-naming-in-content-pages-cs) article and it may help you find the answer.

Comment: dear @un-lucky i have made my code smaller please help

Comment: @JonP basically he is saying he cannot get any values from the gridview in his update method.

Comment: @JonP i have done what u said

Comment: You can try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421938/gridview-how-to-get-the-value-from-a-textbox-in-edit-mdoe) article and i hope your problem sole

Comment: @JonP U understand my problem and one more thing i am getting older values not updated values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your issue is you are binding grid view in each postback, move your BindData method inside the IsPostBack check, then you can get the data

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   Session["page"] = "Employee";
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
      BindData();

      DataTable dt = add.retrive("select * from statemst");

      for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
      {

              ListItem item = new ListItem();
              item.Text = dt.Rows[i]["statedesc"].ToString();
              item.Value = dt.Rows[i]["statecode"].ToString();
              ddl_state.Items.Add(item);
       } 
    }

}
```

Comment: @AnbarasanAnbu please mark this answer.  open questions will check by many other users for answering. you can save their time by mark the answers as answered to your question.